# What's the meaning and structure of this sentense "who should he see waiting but the captain and factor"?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> One morning, early, Mr Fitzwarren had just come to his counting-house
>   and seated himself at the desk, to count over the cash, and settle the
>   business for the day, when somebody came tap, tap, at the door. 'Who's
>   there?' said Mr Fitzwarren. 'A friend,' answered the other; 'I come to
>   bring you good news of your ship Unicorn.' The merchant, bustling up
>   in such a hurry that he forgot his gout, opened the door, and **who**
>   **should he see waiting but the captain and factor**, with a cabinet of
>   jewels and a bill of lading

This is from a English fairly tale. Could you teach me the meaning and structure of "who should he see waiting but the captain and factor"?

Answer (score 1):

"Factor" is [one who acts or transacts business for another, such as a broker](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/factor) (it isn't a commonly used word, at least in modern AmE.

"Who should he see but..." is a story-telling mechanism that sets up a surprise.  Instead of just saying who was there, it asks it as a question and lets you know that the answer was unexpected.

So to paraphrase "who should he see waiting but the captain and factor": "he was surprised to see the captain and broker waiting there".